# How to skip over mask in analysis of OpenCV image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a mask array `mask` and I have two images `F` and `G`. I would like to perform some statistics (some of which may be custom so I need to be able to be able to access the specific elements) on `F` and `G` for only those pixels in which `mask` is true.

I can loop through `F` and `G` and then look at the value of `mask`, but the masking function is pretty liberal, so I really only need to look at maybe .01% of my image. In this case, I am spending 99.99% of the time inside an `if` statement and I want to try to vectorize these operations if possible (or at least cut down on the `if` comparisons since it could be substantial).

My question is - how can I efficiently look at only those pixels in `F` and `G` for which `mask` associates to true (or false ... whichever makes more sense here)?

Comment: 1) Most OpenCV functions accept a mask as input argument. 2) Or you can check the mask value in a for loop, as you mentioned. That isn't _that_ slow, just make it in a clever way. 3) Or you can get all the points that are non-zero in the mask using `findNonZero`. In any case you need to scan the mask. If you have an an example of the operation you want to do, we can come up with a more detailed answer.

Comment: what about using std::vector<cv::Point> instead of mask?

Comment: how should vectorization work/benefit for elements sparsely distributed in memory? Did you think about using sparse Mats in the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out, it makes little sense to talk about vectorizing operations on the original pixels since they will almost certainly not be contiguous in memory.

To account for this, I use a `vector` of `double`'s to store the intensities and then use these contiguous variables in my analysis. In the following code, `X` is an image which I am using as a mask and `R` and `G` are separate images that I want to take intensities from.

```
cv::Mat locs;
cv::findNonZero(X, locs);

std::vector< double > Rs(locs.rows);
std::vector< double > Gs(locs.rows);

for(int ip = 0; ip < locs.rows; ip++) {
    cv::Point p = locs.at<cv::Point>(ip);
    Rs[ip] = ( (double)R.at<uchar>(p) );
    Gs[ip] = ( (double)G.at<uchar>(p) );
}
```

I can then pass this subset to any function I want and work on the data in a vectorized manner if I so choose:

```
double myValue = myFunction( Rs, Gs );
```